# Unknown binary file created in Java environment

Tags: java

I found unknown file created in my Java application environment.
Application is standalone java app with JDK1.7 on CentOS.
The file name consist of numeric characters, may be process id.
I don't know when and why the file was created.
File size is 32KB and the contents is binary as below.(The first part)
[image: (from binary editor)]

I searched for the magic number 0xCAFEC0C0, but i couldn't find any information.
Does anyone know what this file is?

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/jvmstat/index.html?sun/jvmstat/perfdata/monitor/AbstractPerfDataBufferPrologue.html

Comment: user93353 Thanks!I understood it was "hsperfdata" file and  I knew the file is created in hsperfdata directory normally. But the file I found is in execution directory. Is there a case the file created in another directory?